# Datapusher issue (409 Client error) during CKAN setup : maybe a filepath issue?

Tags: installation, filepath, ckan

I'm writting here about a CKAN installation problem. I have already a functional datastore (I've got answer from the API test) and functional filestore, my config file is OK (all options sets, like site.url , etc...). I can post files on the CKAN site, I can get it, SOLR is functional... But I have a remaining problem with datapusher.

The problem is split in two parts :

- When I want to upload files (any file, xls or csv format, with any title.) into datastore with the datapusher, I always get a `409 client Error conflict`. I don't understand why, because the `datapusher.error.log` is empty, and the custom one just shows normal request without error.
- The second one is the fact that, when I want to show a preview of a data, I get the following error:

> "*Could not load view: DataProxy returned an error (Data
>   transformation failed. error: An error occured while connecting to the
>   server: Unable to connect to server at URL:
>   http://192.168.247.109:5000/dataset/004d63d2-c1bb-42fe-8fbe-d9269f22baed/resource/d9c7d014-df71-478e-944b-5c19fb0a74eb/download/poteauxSEM.csv)*"

I think that this error is reliable to the first, but I don't know how.
So I ask to you for some help or answer about similar error (I had research into every documentation, and all stack overflow post.).

**For more information:**

I work on `Debian 8 distrib`, and I've got the following architecture for my files :

```
Ckan virtualenv path : /pyenvs/ckan/
Ckan config files : /pyenvs/ckan/config/ (contain development.ini, who.ini...)
Ckan filestore path : /pyenvs/ckan/files
datapusher path : /pyenvs/datapusher
```

I have tryed all configurations with the datapusher, like default path (instead of my custom path into ckan config files).

Comment: thanks for format and correction alexf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solve, the 409 issue came from the config file, where you cannot type an Ip like this : 192.168.247.109:5000,

you must to type : http://192.168.247.109:5000, even the first one work in a browser.

Sorry for this anoying post.